# Putting cursor at end of textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox that when I put on focus I want the cursor to goto the end of the textbox.

The solution that keeps coming up is just

```
this.value = this.value
```

I have tried this with a simple method onclick:

```
function InputClicked(element) {
    element.className = "inputfocused";
    element.value = element.value;
}
```

but the strange this with this, it seems to goto the end and then jump to the start of the textbox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### You have to focus element AND set caret position

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTFb7) shows you how it works. jQuery has been used for simplicity in this example, but it can be completely omitted if one desires so. `setSelectionRange` function is a DOM function anyway.

In general it does this:

```
input.focus();
input.setSelectionRange(inputValueLength, inputValueLength);
```

Obtaining input and its value length can be obtained using DOM functionality or using library functions (as in jQuery).

### Do we need input value length?

I haven't tested in other browsers but running in Chrome it allows to set a larger than actual position and caret will be positioned at the end. So something like:

```
input.setSelectionRange(1000,1000);
```

will work as expected (provided your text is shorter than 1000 characters. :)

> ***Note***: This function isn't supported in IE8 and older. All latest versions of most used browsers support it. For older versions of IE resort to text ranges.

Comment: This won't work in IE 8 and lower, which doesn't support `setSelectionRange()`.

Comment: @TimDown: That's true. Let me put a note about it above.

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the caret using either the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties or `setSelectionRange()` method of the input. IE < 9 does not support these though, so you need to use the input's [`createTextRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method in those browsers.

Code:

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple And Working 100%

```
1.Focus
2.Take the value
3.Empty It
4.Put the value back 



        $("#catg_name").focus();
        var value = $("#catg_name").val();
        $("#catg_name").val('');
        $("#catg_name").val(value);
```