# KendoEditor Set focus at the end of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendoEditor. I am inserting text in this editor dynamically.
Whenever I insert text in editor , focus of cursor is not getting properly.
I have used below code to focus on editor.

```
        var editor = txt.data("kendoEditor");
        var editorValue = editor.value();
        editor.value('');
        editor.value(editorValue + selectedName);
        editor.focus();
```

with this code, every time it focus at the start of the editor.
But, I need to focus at the end of inserted text.
So, how can I implement this ?
is there any solution about this?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860831/putting-cursor-at-end-of-textbox-in-javascript

Comment: This solution is for input#textbox.  In my case this is KendoEditor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code after editor.focus();

```
var range = editor.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(editor.body);
range.collapse(false);
editor.selectRange(range);
```

Comment: I have one more issue. Can you please help me for that ?

Comment: My issue is related to Anchor tag in KendoEditor. 
Anchor tag Click event is not working in editro.
So, is there any solution for that?

Comment: im afraid there is no solution for that, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: You saved me :D