# Auto scroll the text to left after selecting in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I need to automatically move text to left i.e. the cursor disappears when the list is full. Unless we type, it doesn't show the rightmost word selected.

I tried with,

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

Usage: Type something, eg. "j" to see suggestions for tagging with programming languages. Select a value, then continue typing to add more.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `this.setSelectionRange(1000,1000);` after `this.value = terms.join(", ");`. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860831/putting-cursor-at-end-of-textbox-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting cursor at end of textbox in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860831/putting-cursor-at-end-of-textbox-in-javascript)

Comment: No cursor will not move to the right end. it will remain hidden. Any alternatives?