# Is there another way to write cleaner code for an HTML attribute using JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to using JavaScript and HTML. I have a textbox and I'm using the onfocus attribute in HTML on a textbox to display a cursor at the end of this number:

```
<input type="text" id="TextInput" onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(1000,1001);" />
```

and I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to write `onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(1000,1001);"` using an external js file and calling the function to the onfocus method instead of hardcoding it. I'm just trying to achieve clean code but I think my syntax is off or that I'm calling the method incorrectly.

Comment: That would highlight a character at a specific position, not focus the cursor at the end.

Comment: there character is usually only 3 digits max so I put that range so it would go to the end. Is there a better way to do this? @j08691

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860831/putting-cursor-at-end-of-textbox-in-javascript

Comment: the link you pointed me told me to 
input.focus();
input.setSelectionRange(inputValueLength, inputValueLength);

if i am using a spinner Primefaces which is similar to a textbox, how would I write this in order to achieve the length, without using jQuery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best practice on adding event listeners (javascript, html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925146/best-practice-on-adding-event-listeners-javascript-html)

Comment: Use `addEventListener` instead of the `on*` HTML attributes for attaching event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok. I would only change harcoded numbers:

```
this.setSelectionRange(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

And maybe you want to use it with autofocus:

```
<input type="text" value="example text" autofocus onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);" />
```